# How do i use "TImageEnVect.SetObjPolylinePoints" function in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-7, pascal

I have an image and points that belong this image. I added image with points that belong the image below:

[image]

My code's summary is added below:

```
PPArray : array of TPoint;`
.
.
PPArray := FindCellPolygonPoints(CenterP,BrownMask, 40);
ImageEnVect1.SetObjPolylinePoints(???,PPArray);
```

How do i use this function or could you help me to create polygon by using these points with another method?

Comment: http://www.imageen.com/help/ImageEn/TImageEnVect.SetObjPolylinePoints.html

Comment: Thanks, i know this page but i could not apply. I do not understand what is the hobj?

Comment: It's an object identifier. Try pass -1. Or put a question on the forum of the component vendor.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by adding to my code`hobj:= ImageEnVect1.AddNewObject(iekPOLYLINE, Blob.BoundingBox, clGreen);`part. Thanks for your helps.